# Subsetting a large data set based on a list of strings in R

Tags: r, subset, fread

I have a large data set of patient data consisting of 40 .txt files each 1-2gb that I have made a list of (list_lab). Each file has the exact same amount of columns (29). I would like to make one data table from the 40 text files, and I only need 5 of the columns

```
c("PAT_MRN_ID", "LAB_RSLT_COLLECTION_DTTM", "LAB_TEST", "LAB_RSLT_VALUE", "ORDERING_DATE")
```

for the data table. I will then need to subset the data using values from the column "PAT_MRN_ID" and a list of 125 strings (list_MRN). I have tried to make the data table, but I believe it is too large.

Initially, I tried to create a data table with everything with the plan of parsing down columns afterwards using

```
lab_dt <- rbindlist(lapply(list_lab, fread), fill = TRUE)
```

After 8 hours, I received the message

> "Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)"

I tried to select for only the columns I needed using

```
lab_dt <- rbindlist(lapply(list_lab, fread (select = c("PAT_MRN_ID", "LAB_RSLT_COLLECTION_DTTM", "LAB_TEST", "LAB_RSLT_VALUE", "ORDERING_DATE"))), fill = TRUE)
```

but received this message:

> "Error in fread(select = c("PAT_MRN_ID", "LAB_RSLT_COLLECTION_DTTM",
> "LAB_TEST",  :    Input is empty or only contains BOM or terminal
> control characters"

Is there a way to select for only the columns I want to be read in to the data table? This is unfortunately on a remote server that I am not currently able to run command lines through terminal on OSX.

Second, would it be faster or more efficient to subset the data as it is being read?

Comment: Check out [vroom](https://vroom.r-lib.org/). It lazy loads the data so that only if you use a column, is it read from disk. This should allow you to discard the columns you don't need without using up all the memory.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong for the second approach. Try this:

```
library(data.table)
mycols <- c("PAT_MRN_ID", "LAB_RSLT_COLLECTION_DTTM", "LAB_TEST", "LAB_RSLT_VALUE", "ORDERING_DATE")

rbindlist(lapply(list_lab, \(x) fread(x, select = mycols)))
```

To experiment a bit more efficiently you could also specify the `nrows` agrument of `fread` to speed things up a bit more:

```
rbindlist(lapply(list_lab, \(x) fread(x, select = mycols, nrows = 10)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I see the syntax problem. Entering that code results in 
"Taking input= as a system command ('file name.txt') and a variable has been used in the expression passed to `input=`. Please use fread(cmd=...). There is a security concern if you are creating an app, and the app could have a malicious user, and the app is not running in a secure environment; e.g. the app is running as root. Please read item 5 in the NEWS file for v1.11.6 for more information and for the option to suppress this message.
sh: 34042: command not found"